# How do I query subset of columns from PostGIS using MyBatis?

Tags: java, ibatis, postgis, mybatis

I'm trying to query data from a PostGIS database using MyBatis, ignoring the geospatial data. I have the following table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE salesgeometry
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  label character varying(255),
  type character varying(255),
  geom geometry,
  CONSTRAINT salesgeometry_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_geom CHECK (st_ndims(geom) = 2),
  CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_geom CHECK (st_srid(geom) = 4326)
)
```

I'm trying to map this with MyBatis using this annotation:

```
@Select("SELECT id, type, label FROM salesgeometry WHERE ST_Within(" +
        "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(#{longitude} #{latitude})', 4326), geom) " +
        "AND type = #{type}")
Geometry getGeometryAtLocation(
        @NotNull @Param("type") String geometryType,
        @NotNull @Param("longitude") BigDecimal longitude, 
        @NotNull @Param("latitude") BigDecimal latitude
);
```

And the target class has fields like this:

```
public class Geometry {
    private long id;
    private String type;
    private String label;
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work, instead I get a

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
```

How do I query just the subset of columns from the database?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(#{longitude} #{latitude})', 4326)` is mapped by MyBatis to a prepared statement looking like this: `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)', 4326)`, which doesn't actually contain the expected parameters since the question marks are within quotes.

The solution is to either use string concatenation (as in `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || #{longitude} || ' ' || #{latitude} || ')', 4326)` or use string substitution instead: `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${longitude} ${latitude})', 4326)`, which puts the values into the SQL statement directly instead of using parameters of prepared statements.

The following mapping works (note the two dollar symbols for longitude and latitude):

```
@Select("SELECT id, type, label FROM salesgeometry WHERE ST_Within(" +
        "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(${longitude} ${latitude})', 4326), geom) " +
        "AND type = #{type}")
Geometry getGeometryAtLocation(
        @NotNull @Param("type") String geometryType,
        @NotNull @Param("longitude") BigDecimal longitude, 
        @NotNull @Param("latitude") BigDecimal latitude
);
```